# Architecture of sub-classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I learn C++ OOP-paradigm and want to ask related question:

### **Assumption**

We have a base class:

```
class Base { 
public:
    virtual SomeType PowerMethod() { return SomeType{} };
}
```

We have a variable `target` and subclass which realizes some calculations with target variable based on the constructor's parameter (simple calculations or complicated calcs):

```
class Calc : public Base {
public: // using only public access to simplify real code structure
    SomeType target;
    void Simple() { target = 1; };
    void Complex(){ target = 10000; };

    explicit Calc(bool isSimple) { 
        if(isSimple) 
            Simple(); 
        else
            Complex();
    }
};
```

### **Question**

How to optimally realize **two classes** which based on different methods (Simple or Complex) but provide the same functionality of PowerMethod()?

### **My solution**

```
class SimpleCalc : public Calc {
    bool isSimple = true;
public:
    SomeType PowerMethod() override { 
        Calc CalcInstance(isSimple);
        return CalcInstance.target;
    };
};


class ComplexCalc : public Calc {
    bool isSimple = false;
public:
    SomeType PowerMethod() override { 
        Calc CalcInstance(isSimple);
        return CalcInstance.target;
    };
};
```

This solution is pretty "ugly" and I want to ask you how to make it more readable.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to create a new `Calc` object, or instantiate the superclass?

Comment: Looks like the meber `bool isSimple` is redundant. You can rely on polymorphic dispatch to use `SimpleCalc::PowerMethod()` or `ComplexCalc::PowerMethod()` depending on the actual type of your object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your code, you didn't mean to craete a new Calc object, but instead call it on the superclass. This can be done like so:

```
Calc::Simple();
```

You can override the method `PowerMethod`, but still call the superclass's code:

```
virtual SomeType PowerMethod() override {
   //do something
   Base::PowerMethod();
}
```

If your problem is more complicated, and polymorphism and superclasses can't help you, you can always declare some method protected, so that only subclasses can access it. So, you could for example do this:

```
class Calc : public Base {
protected:
    SomeType target;
    void Simple() { target = 1; };
    void Complex(){ target = 10000; };
public:
    explicit Calc(bool isSimple) { 
        if(isSimple) 
            Simple(); 
        else
            Complex();
    }
};
```

```
class SimpleCalc : public Calc {
public:
    SomeType PowerMethod() override { 
        Calc::Simple();
        return Calc::target;
    };
};


class ComplexCalc : public Calc {
public:
    SomeType PowerMethod() override { 
        Calc::Complex();
        return Calc::target;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! In product case it's necessary to create two child classes with definite aliases (SimpleCalc, ComplexCalc), so question was how to avoid double usage of the same code in such classes

Comment: Then you should do it like in the example.

Answer (score -1):

If your target is to learn OOP then you can use a factory design pattern to create your final calculator based on isSimple condition:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base 
{
public:

    Base()
    {
        target = 0;
    }

    int target;

    virtual void PowerMethod() = 0;
};

class SimpleCalc : public Base
{
    virtual void PowerMethod() { target = 0; }
};

class ComplexCalc : public Base
{
    virtual void PowerMethod() { target = 1000; }
};

class CalcFactory
{
public:
    virtual Base* createCalc(bool isSimple) 
    {
        if (isSimple)
            return new SimpleCalc();
        else
            return new ComplexCalc();
    }
};

int main()
{
    CalcFactory factory;
    Base * base1 = factory.createCalc(true);
    Base * base2 = factory.createCalc(false);
    
    base1->PowerMethod();
    base2->PowerMethod();

    std::cout << base1->target << std::endl;
    std::cout << base2->target << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Factories are a bit overkill in this situation, and they only complicate the code further

Comment: @PromitheasNikou my code looks cleaner than the original version... but maybe I'm wrong